# IBM MobileFirst Server - Hosting Static Content

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Is there a way to host static content like help text on an IBM MobileFirst Server?

I have a Native Android application with a MobileFirst Server backend. I want an adapter to return text that I can update on my MobileFirst Server dynamically.

Is this possible? If so whats the best way to perform this?

Edit: The end goal here is to be able to modify text inside the application without requiring an app update. For example, (this may not be a good way of doing this) creating an adapter that when called, will access a document stored in the mobilefirst server and return it. This document stored on the server will need to be able to be modified whenever we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MobileFirst Server and its database are not meant for serving "content" such as what you're looking for.

You can use the same host machine, or a different machine, to host another database or some other service, a file server, and query it using a SQL/HTTP adapter (depending on what you'll select) in order to retrieve the static content, parse it and use jQuery APIs to inject it into the DOM, replacing whatever is currently there.

Comment: Updated my question. Thanks Idan

Comment: So your question is not about how to implement this, rather whether you can or cannot use the MobileFirst Server to store this content? The answer is the same then.